# My Angular component is not loading in the Office Word Addin action pane, though it works fine outside the office environment

Tags: angular, ms-word, office365, office-js, word-addins

I am developing an Office word addin using Angular, I got the addin loads in the Word action pane, but the Angular component is not loading (eg:- home component). Below is my code.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <script>
    __Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
  </script>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Addin</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <!-- Office JavaScript API -->
  <script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js"></script>
  <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.debug.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.ts**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

Office.initialize = () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic()
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
};
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-home></app-home>
```

**home.component.html**

```
<p>home works</p>
```

As you can see that there I have not written any logic yet. All I want to see is the text "home works" in the word addin pane.

As mentioned [in this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-ins-with-angular2), I have already done the changes in the **app.modules.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
    // Other providers suppressed
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ]
})
```

I have also tried using the IE Debug tool (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\F12\IEChooser.exe), but the console logs are not coming there as well.

Am I missing anything here? Any help is really appreciated!.

**Update:**

The solution works on my friends's machine and we both uses the same version of Office products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I tried many things, some of them are below.

1. Check the app with different node version
2. Update the Office
3. Reinstall the Office
4. Do the complete sideloading of the app, multiple times

None of them worked, at the end what worked for was, **Updating the Windows 10**. Yeah, I was using the Windows 10 version 1903, and **updating it to the version 1909** fixed my issue.

[image]

[image]